# Write a python code to evaluate the recursive formula

Tags: python

In a game where each turn is made up of the roll of a die, player E gets one point when the die is even, and player O gets one point when the die is odd. The first player to accumulate 7 points wins the pot. Suppose the die is fair and the game is interrupted with E leading 4−2. Write Python 3 code to evaluate the recursive formula to determine the fraction of money that E gets in the above situation where `p = 0.5, e = 4, o = 2 and m = 7`. Write down E’s proportion.

From the problem given, we can derive that `p = 0.5, m = 7, e = 4, o = 2`. Let A be the event player E is winning where `m - e = 3` rounds from winning and B be the event player O is winning `m - o = 5` rounds from winning. `P(A,B) = p.P(A-1,B) + (1-p)P(A,B-1)` with boundary `P(0,k)=1, P(k,0) = 0` for all positive integer k. Hence, the general recursive formula will be `P(m-e, m-o) = p.P(m-e-1,m-o) + (1-p)P(m-e, m-o-1)$ in terms of $p, m, e, o`.

However, I am unsure of how to translate from this mathematical formula I derived into a Python code?

Comment: Do you know how to do recursion in Python? That is, how to write recursive functions?

Comment: https://www.python-course.eu/recursive_functions.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need recursion for that problem. You want to know what's the probability of getting 3 evens before you get 5 odds. This means we need the probability of getting at least 3 evens in the next 3+5-1 = 7 attempts (because if you only get 2 evens, you'll have gotten 5 odds and O will win).

It's much easier to write a non-recursive function that simply calculates the quantity you need this way, using all the parameters (p, e, o, m). You can also set the probability for the winning side if the die is not fair:

```
from itertools import permutations

def combos(win, avail):
    array = [1]*win + [0]*(avail-win)
    return len(set(permutations(array)))

def win_probability(p_winner, winner_score, loser_score, max_score):
    winner_needs = max_score - winner_score
    loser_needs = max_score - loser_score
    available_rolls = winner_needs + loser_needs - 1
    prob = 0
    for winner_rolls in range(winner_needs, available_rolls + 1):
        prob += combos(winner_rolls, available_rolls) \
            * p_winner ** winner_rolls \
            * (1 - p_winner) ** (available_rolls - winner_rolls)
    return prob

print(win_probability(.5,4,2,7))

'''
Out:
    0.7734375
'''
```